# iOS: How to add multiple day data into Health Kit Store

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm looking into Research Kit and Health Kit. Testing wise on the simulator I don't have any data - massive issue :)

How would one get data (most specifically, steps) into the HealthKit Store? Below is what I got, which doesn't appear to fail but nothing is shown within the Health app dashboard. I want this to provide 14 days worth of data...

```
var date:NSDate! = NSDate()

let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
dateComponents.day = -13

let endingDate:NSDate! = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions())

while date.compare(endingDate) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
    let countRate = Double(arc4random_uniform(500) * arc4random_uniform(10))
    let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
    let quantity = HKQuantity(unit: stepsUnit, doubleValue: countRate)
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = -1
    date = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions())
    let sample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)!, quantity: quantity, startDate: date, endDate: date)

    HKHealthStore().saveObject(sample, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
        if let _ = error {
            print("Error saving sample: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me this appears to work. You need to go into "Health Data" tab and basically select whatever you're after (in this case Fitness > Steps) and it'll show you all the data!

You can also select the tab to show on dashboard too so the initial launch of the app won't look empty!

I'll leave this here for anyone that wants a mini code sample + if they come across not realising where the data can be displayed!